# How to add Java project instead of Jar in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, tomcat

I am working on two connected projects, my current solution looks like that:

My main project is web app (spring + vaadin), which use JAR build by ant in second project. Now I have to debug the second project (JAR) but I can't connect it :|

I tried add my second project as "Required project" but it did not do the magic. 
I tried add sources to JAR, but it did not do the magic.

Any suggestion how can I do that ?

Aaand -> my problem is on Tomcat, I want to debug both projects at the same time. And now I can not run it.

thx 
Lukasz

---

log:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ln/wi/search/service/WIService
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:1836)
```

Comment: adding project 2 to the build path of project 1 should resolve this.  When you check the build path for project 1, is project 2 listed there under required projects?

Comment: Yes it is. I tried cleaning tomcat/projects/everything... Still same exception, still I can't run project 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to adding it to the build path, you also want to add the second project to the Deployment Assembly page of the project's Properties (assuming you're on a recent version of Eclipse which has that capability).

Comment: Exactly ! :) Thank you, you just save my day :)

Answer (score 3):

Right click on the web app project and select Build Path > Configure Build Path, then select the Projects tab and add the jar project as a dependency. Eclipse will set it up on the class path for you.

Otherwise, you could use maven and create a multi module project where the jar is automatically packaged and added to the WEB-INF/lib folder of the Web App project, but that could be an overkill :)

cheers

Comment: I have done this and it is not working for me. I have got exception from my previous post. Any other idea ?